# How make Safari 7 open PDF files in Preview instead of opening them in-page?

Tags: safari, pdf, preview

Since Safari 7.0 which was introduced yesterday with OS X Mavericks the little terminal hack

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool YES
```

doesn't work anymore (at least not for me).

Once you use the Terminal hack, the PDF is shown in binary/ascii-format in a new tab of Safari (like if you would open the file with TextEdit instead of an arbitrary PDF reader):

[image: content of pdf in safari]

Any suggestions how to achieve the desired behavior anyway?

Answer (score 5):

Just adding support to find an answer to this issue. I suppose in the meantime do this:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool NO
```

Answer (score 3):

Holding <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> down while clicking it makes it download it. That is with the old hack still marked `YES`. Not the best solution, but will do for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

For Me this was not enough. I had do de following:

1. Type in Terminal.app:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool YES
   ```

   This disables pdf support in Safari.
2. Restart Safari
3. Type in Terminal app:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool NO
   ```

   This enables pdf support in Safari.
4. Restart Safari and reload pdf page.