# Blocked Plug-in in Safari 10.1

Tags: safari, pdf

I'm running El Captain 10.11.6 (15G1421) with all updates. I've recently updated to Safari 10.1 (11603.1.30.0.34) and now I get "Blocked Plug-in" whenever I click on Gmail links that lead to a PDF or even to a web page that links to a PDF.

[image]

Copying the link and opening it on a new window or tab works just fine! So does control-click,but not option-click or command-click.

Is there a fix or a better workaround? Can we tell Safari to always open PDFs in Preview?

Opening a console shows

> Refused to load http://URL/foo.pdf because it does not appear in the object-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Here is my full Installed Plugins list:

- Google Talk Plugin
- Google Talk Plugin Video Renderer
- Java Applet Plug-in
- and a online banking plugin.

I do have Adobe Reader 10.1.16 installed but I don't think I've installed a browser plugin for that. The "Blocked Plug-in" message does not mention Adobe.

The problem also occurs in a different machine also running El Captain that does not have Adobe Reader.

Comment: What plugin do you use? Adobe Reader? Then try this link (note that this is for older versions): https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/blocked-plugin-alert-safari-7.html

Comment: See also ["Blocked Plug-In" when opening pdf from Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7912093).

Comment: Have you tried updating to the newest version of Adobe Reader? Seems you're a few version out of date https://get.adobe.com/reader/

Comment: @ToddDabney, like I said, the problem is *not* with Adobe Reader.

Comment: Strangely, PDFs load just fine if you Command-click and choose 'Open link in a new tab'.

Comment: I'm on Safari 14.0, and the problem just started to occurred a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Safari 11.0 no longer exhibits this problem.

Comment: The problem persists in Safari Version 11.0.2

Comment: @k_rus, not for me. I'm using Safari Version 11.0.2 (11604.4.7.1.6), recently released.

Answer (score 6):

Without clicking the back button (or `Command-[` ) of the browser:

1. Although the plugin is blocked, you can still use Command-S (or File > Save As) as well as File > Export as PDF to save the file to a folder.

Alternatively, click the back button (or `Command-[` ), and then:

1. Option-click on the original link to download the file
2. Command-click opens the PDF in a new tab (PDF will not be blocked)
3. Ctrl-click yields the option "Download linked file as"

Comment: Ah, you can save the file from the "Blocked Plug-in" page! I wish I could open Preview directly but the floating "bar" does not appear at the bottom. But like I said, control-click works but not option-click or command-click.

Comment: Can we tell Safari to always open PDFs in Preview?

Comment: This question was asked here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106660/how-make-safari-7-open-pdf-files-in-preview-instead-of-opening-them-in-page  Apparently, none of the methods work in the current version of Safari (10.1)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a clue. I am having the same problem. It started yesterday when I installed Adobe Reader DC and selected custom install and chose not to install the Adobe Reader browser extension. Before this PDFs were showing with options to open in Preview or download.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the pdf link and open in new tab. Its worked for me.

Comment: A block plugin doesn't become unblocked when you open the link in a new tab.

Comment: Its worked for me. One of my trade statement coming as link to pdf. If i clicks it, it shows blocked plug-in. When I right clicked and opened in new window it worked for me and still works fine for me. You pls check yourself and post back.
If allowed I can share the screenshots now. Bcz it still works for me.

Comment: Depending what the underlying problem is, this does sometimes work. If the PDF is blocked by a bad content security policy on the site, then this can work around it in Safari.

Comment: Doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, if you can resolve the problem.

Right click on any pdf file visible in Finder and press on "Get Info" menu.

[image]

Select "Preview.app" as default, if it is not selected and Press on "Change All..." button in "Get Info" window.

Refresh tab in Safari in that url is pdf file.

And You will see pdf file inside Safari.

Hope your issue may be resolved.

Thanks.