# How can I create a shortcut to open Safari PDF in Preview?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, safari, pdf, preview

If I open a PDF file in Safari (say, from a website), it is shown in a browser window or tab, and from there I can hover over the bottom of the page and from there click on this overlay to open the PDF in Preview:

[image]

How can I make a shortcut (or alternatively, write an AppleScript), so that I can open the PDF in Preview directly, without hunting around for the overlay and clicking the pointer on the appropriate icon in the overlay?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106660/how-make-safari-7-open-pdf-files-in-preview-instead-of-opening-them-in-page

Answer (score 2):

- General tab in Safari preferences.

  > Open “safe” files after downloading
  >
  > In Safari, automatically open the listed types of files but not software.

  https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/safari/ibrw1072/12.0/mac/10.14.5
- I don't know if you count right click as "hunting around", but you can right click on an empty part of the PDF and select "open with preview". Note that the point of click shouldn't be surrounded by content of the PDF.
- You can always use Automator with or without AppleScript to do the same and then bind a shortcut with that Service/ Quick Action.

Comment: It would be preferable to avoid saving the file locally for some situations, but okay, that's a possible solution, albeit with implications for other file types. Regarding "Open with Preview", it seems it's not always available on all PDFs – I don't know why.

Comment: click on the right place.. away from all the text/ pictures.